# jsoncpp : error while building the documentation

Tags: python, shell, jsoncpp

I'm trying to build jsoncpp's documentation (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) in Ubuntu 14.10. As said in the github's README.md, I run the doxybuild.py script but I get the following error :

```
$> cd jsoncpp/
$> python doxybuild.py --doxygen=$(which doxygen) --open --with-dot
Deleting directory: dist/doxygen
Running:  /home/jeremy/Projets/Perso/CmdSeries/libs/jsoncpp/doc/doxyfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "doxybuild.py", line 169, in <module>
    main()
  File "doxybuild.py", line 166, in main
    build_doc( options )
  File "doxybuild.py", line 116, in build_doc
    ok = run_doxygen( options.doxygen_path, 'doc/doxyfile', 'doc', is_silent=options.silent )
  File "doxybuild.py", line 67, in run_doxygen
    process = subprocess.Popen( cmd )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

$> sudo python doxybuild.py --doxygen=$(which doxygen) --open --with-dot
Deleting directory: dist/doxygen
Running:  /home/jeremy/Projets/Perso/CmdSeries/libs/jsoncpp/doc/doxyfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "doxybuild.py", line 169, in <module>
    main()
  File "doxybuild.py", line 166, in main
    build_doc( options )
  File "doxybuild.py", line 116, in build_doc
    ok = run_doxygen( options.doxygen_path, 'doc/doxyfile', 'doc', is_silent=options.silent )
  File "doxybuild.py", line 67, in run_doxygen
    process = subprocess.Popen( cmd )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Already tried :

- chmod u+x doxybuild.py
- sudo chmod 775 /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py
- sudo chown $USER /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py

But nothing resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, problem solved :

```
$> cd jsoncpp/doc
$> cat readme.txt
The documentation is generated using doxygen (http://www.doxygen.org).
$> sudo apt-get install doxygen
... 
OK
$> python doxybuild.py --doxygen=$(which doxygen) --open --with-dot
...
ok
```

Just install doxygen and building the documentation will work.